# CentOS server - where should I store my scripts?

Tags: centos, directory

I have CentOS server with WHM and few cPanel accounts. I connect to it using `ssh`. All cPanel accounts are stored in `/home` directory.

> centos-release-7-2.1511.el7.centos.2.10.x86_64

I also have Ubuntu 14.04 server on which I store all my development scripts in `/var/www/html` folder and run it under apache2.

Where should I run my scripts on CentOS server? Should I create new cPanel account for it or should I create `/var/www/html` folder for apache?

My scripts are usually written in PHP and Shell.

I apologize in advance for being offtopic and asking for recommendation.

Comment: Your question is vague... there's *no* reason to store scripts in a web-accessible location, unless you're specifically designing a local web site.

Comment: Also, FWIW, it's generally "dangerous" to mix HTML content and scripts. Ideally, even on a webserver, they should be kept in separate directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache was already installed with Cpanel on CentOS 7.2. Create folder in /home and set ownership to root:nobody to allow apache to access it. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS 7.2 `/var/www/html` is automatically created when installing Apache httpd and is functionally similar to Ubuntu's directory:

```
[root@t-wiki ~]# rpm -ql httpd | grep /var/www/html
/var/www/html
[root@t-wiki ~]# ls -l /var/www/html
total 0
[root@t-wiki ~]# rpm -q httpd
httpd-2.4.6-40.el7_2.1.x86_64
```

Comment: This is strange beacause I am using `centos-release-7-2.1511.el7.centos.2.10.x86_64
` and there is no /var/www/html. `[root@cpanel1 ~]# ls /var/
adm    cpanel  db     games   kerberos  local  log   named  opt       profiles  spool  yp
cache  crash   empty  gopher  lib       lock   mail  nis    preserve  run       tmp`

Comment: No package httpd available.

Comment: It's actually in the [OS Repo](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/). Verify it's enabled in /etc/yum.repos.d/